# Is there a connection between the movies Indiana Jones and the Last Crusade and All Through the Night?

Tags: analysis, indiana-jones, all-through-the-night

Does anyone know if there was a conscious borrowing of content or scenes from the Humphrey Bogart movie **All Through the Night** in the movie **Indiana Jones and the Last Crusade**?

For example:

- In **All Through the Night**, there is an action scene late in the film that involves a motorboat. There is an action scene in **Indiana Jones and the Last Crusade** that involves motorboats that look identical to the model used in All Through the Night.
- In **All Through the Night**, Humphrey Bogart makes the comment, "I always turn up. I'm like a bad penny." **In Indiana Jones and the Last Crusade**, Indy says near the end, "I'm like a bad penny. I always turn up."
- There's a sequence in **All Through the Night** where Bogart and his buddy being tied up in a warehouse by baddies. A woman comes to see them and can't untie them. Bogart's solution is to have her fetch his lighter. In **Indiana Jones and the Last Crusade**, there's a scene where Indy and his father are tied up. A woman comes to visit and although she is a baddie and doesn't help them escape, their solution to getting free involves a lighter.
- In **All Through the Night**, the protagonists impersonate nazis and end up at a meeting discussing sabotage plans. Indy and his father impersonate nazis and end up in Berlin during a book burning.
- In **All Through the Night**, the female lead appears to flip flop sides throughout the film, starting out a mystery, straying into what looks like a baddie, only to end up on the side of the good guys. In **Indiana Jones and the Last Crusade**, the female lead also switches sides, starting out on the good side, revealing an alliance with the baddies only to flip back to the good guys side in the climax (briefly, I grant you).

More minor points that aren't convincing on their own include, both movies having nazis as baddies (whereas previously, Indy's second outing had been a prequel and hadn't involved nazis) and secret societies (With Bogart it's an espionage cell, with Indy its a society that protects the Holy Grail).

While these last two minor points wouldn't be convincing in and of themselves, taken with the others it seems like there could be some borrowing in terms of details or plot events (certainly not in plots as they are both drastically different).

1. Does anyone know if Spielberg or anyone involved in the making of **Indiana Jones and the Last Crusade** was a big fan of **All Through the Night**?
2. Was some of its content borrowed in some respect for the big Indy flick?

Comment: I don't know about "The Last Crusade" but RotLA itself is an uncredited remake of "Secret of the Incas", which fact Spielberg/Lucas kept very well hidden for years. So I'd say it's far from impossible.

Comment: Google "spielberg plagiarized".  It was quite a common practice for him to steal complete or partial storylines from previous works, and he's had several lawsuits because of it.

Answer (score -3):

Those are great observations. The film definitely influenced All Through The Night and other Humphrey Bogart films, especially Casablanca. The way they use the map in Indiana Jones from Europe to Morocco is one, the market streets, Rick's club, etc. These are classic masterpieces, so a lot of directors use these as homages to the films.

Comment: Are you saying *Indiana Jones* influenced *Casablanca*? You do know Casablanca came first, right?